# File's pyshical memory location or variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I just started to learn about pointers, and opening to files. So, when I use the `FILE` datatype in order to open an existing file for reading, the pointer points to the file memory location or to the variable memory location?

```
#include <stdio.h> // I/O

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fpointer = fopen("employees", "r");
    fclose(fpointer);

    return 0;
}
```

If the pointer points to the memory location of the file, when I print the pointer, the output will be the exact file location in the memory?

```
printf("memory address: %p\n", fpointer);
// i.e 0x55a5ca11a2a0
```

Comment: The file isn't in your process memory.  It's on some storage device (e.g. a disk).  The file pointer points to a structure that contains buffering information.  When reading the file, it is read in chunks which are stored in a buffer.  When more is needed, an I/O call is made to read more of the file.

Comment: @TomKarzes `The file isn't in your process memory` Yeah I know. But I thought that the variable holds the file location because in order to open it he needs it's location. Good to know!

Comment: The FILE is a struct for a description.  That struct contains everything the OS needs to know about that file. like physical location on disk, current file pointer (which is usually the current (in linux) `inode` of the file, buffers for input and output, etc.  Calling `fopen()` returns a pointer to an instance of that struct.  Those struct instances are kept in an array and calling `open()` returns an index into that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't hold the "file location", it holds a filehandle, which is something issued by the operating system when a file is opened and allows you to read and/or write from it.

The `FILE` structure not only includes the handle, it has a small amount of memory set aside for buffers, too, to improve performance.

You can probably find the exact definition of how `FILE` works in the header file.

Here's an example definition:

```
struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;           /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  char *_IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char *_IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char *_IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char *_IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char *_IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char *_IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char *_IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char *_IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */

  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```